# Inheriting public/protected/private constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, using, access-modifiers

If I understand correctly:

```
class Base { /*...*/ };
class Derived: public Base { public: using Base::Base; }
```

will enforce inheritance of all `Base` constructors in `Derived`.

But what about public/protected/private constructors?

```
class Base {
    friend void g();
public:
    Base (A a);
protected:
    Base (B b);
private:
    Base (C c);
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    using Derived::Derived;
};
```

I can't find any specification on this, but I tried the following:

```
void f () {
    Derived{A{}}; // OK
    Derived{B{}}; // Inaccessible
    Derived{C{}}; // Inaccessible
}

void g () {
    Derived{A{}}; // OK
    Derived{B{}}; // OK
    Derived{C{}}; // OK
}
```

So it seems, that `using Base::Base` doesn't take the access modifiers into consideration when deciding which constructors to inherit (it inherits the private one) but it inherits them with those modifiers (private/protected ones remain inaccessible to others) and it allows private/protected access to friends of `Base` (friendship is not inherited, so `g` is not a friend of `Derived`, but it still can access private/protected constructor of `Derived` inherited from `Base`).

Is that correct and standard behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification you are looking for is in **[namespace.udecl]** [¶19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#19), emphasis mine.

> A *using-declarator* that names a constructor does not create a synonym;
>   **instead, the additional constructors are accessible if they would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base
>   class**, and the accessibility of the *using-declaration* is ignored.

Your testing is consistent with that paragraph. The accessibility checks fail or pass exactly as they would when constructing a `Base` in the scopes you check.